# C#: Merging multi-database driver interface

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, mongodb

I decided to write wrappers, but for two different database drivers, MySQL and MongoDB. I was going to use them seperatly but then decided why not make my application multi-driver compatible? Running MongoDB and MySQL side by side, and a configuration value to chose the driver.

I later realised theres a lot of different in filtering, updating, and the parameters that would need to be passed to these methods, and to run them on one interface (IDatabase) would be difficult, in fact it would be impossible for me as I don't know how..

I'm asking fro some help with logically merging these to work with one interface, so I can use them both (multi driver) in one app? I've wrote the methods below

```
MongoDB:
UpdateOneRecord(string collection, List<UpdateDefinition<BsonDocument>> updateDefinitions, List<FilterDefinition<BsonDocument>> filterDefinitions = null)
UpdateManyRecords(string collection, List<List<UpdateDefinition<BsonDocument>>> updateDefinitions, List<List<FilterDefinition<BsonDocument>>> filterDefinitions = null)
InsertOneRecord(string collection, TDocument insertDocument)
InsertManyRecords(string collection, List<TDocument> insertDocuments)
DeleteRecords(string collection, List<FilterDefinition<BsonDocument>> filterDefinitions = null)
GetTableCount(string collection, List<FilterDefinition<BsonDocument>> filterDefinitions = null)
GetDataTable(string collection, List<string> selectParts, List<FilterDefinition<BsonDocument>> filterDefinitions = null)
GetDataRow(string collection, List<string> selectParts, List<FilterDefinition<BsonDocument>> filterDefinitions = null)

MySQL:
UpdateOneRecord(string table, Dictionary<string, string> updateDefinitions, Dictionary<string, string> filterDefinitions = null, string customFilter = "")
UpdateManyRecords(string table, List<Dictionary<string, string>> updateDefinitions, List<Dictionary<string, string>> filterDefinitions = null, List<string> customFilters = null)
InsertOneRecord(string table, Dictionary<string, string> insertDefinitions)
InsertManyRecords(string table, List<Dictionary<string, string>> insertDefinitions)
DeleteRecords(string table, Dictionary<string, string> filterDefinitions = null, string customFilter = "")
GetTableCount(string table, Dictionary<string, string> filterDefinitions = null, string customFilter = "")
GetDataTable(string table, List<string> selectParts, Dictionary<string, string> filterDefinitions = null, string customFilter = "")
GetDataRow(string table, List<string> selectParts, Dictionary<string, string> filterDefinitions = null, string customFilter = "")
```

That's the whole question, although I have included code below to explain my setup further.

I have a class called DatabaseHandler, that returns a IDatabaseConnection interface (the interface both MongoDB and MySQL will inherit)

```
public IDatabaseConnection GetNewConnection()
{
    if (_databaseDriver == "mysql") {
        return new MySqlDbConnection(_mysqlConnectionStr);
    }

    return new MongoDbConnection(_mongoClient, _mongoDatabase);
}
```

Then of course both classes, `MySqlDbConnection` and `MongoDbConnection` inherit the IDatabaseConnection class on the class with all the methods above.

The issue is, the interface will force both classes to have the same methods, and the same parameters.

I can't see a way around this, hopefully someone else can help. I'm really not "switched on" or logical when it comes to programming and creating good systems.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: don't try to write code against particular database engines.

---

The point of the `IDatabaseConnection` interface is that it provides a consistent list of properties and methods that you can reasonably expect to function in similar ways.  This way you don't have to worry about writing code that targets a particular database, you just write something that works with *any* `IDatabaseConnection` implementation.

The reality can be a little different of course.  MySQL and SQLServer for instance have subtly different query languages.  When I write `SELECT TOP <n>...` for SQLServer I know that I'm locked into a particular database, and that query will fail on pretty much everything else.

The solution generally is to use a library that abstracts those concerns away.  On .NET the standard answer is Entity Frameworks 6, but I find that too clunky and overblown.  Having used EF6 a few times I've decided that it really doesn't fit with me.  Linq to SQL (L2S) is much more my style, and you can use it for any DB that implements some basics like `IDatabaseConnection`.

In L2S (or EF6, or...) you write your queries using LINQ expressions and the library figures out how to run the query on the server.  In the case of `TOP <n>` vs `LIMIT <n>` the LINQ query looks the same:

```
var query = db.SomeTable.Take(10);
```

When I enumerate that query the library generates the appropriate SQL for getting just 10 results.  It handles all sorts of things like that for you, like a good library should.  And it does so - to my surprise at times - quite well.

I occasionally hand-code SQL, but these days not as often as I used to.  Sure, I miss CTEs and `MERGE` sometimes, but that's why we have views and stored procedures.

---

My current DB library of choice is [linq2db](https://linq2db.github.io/).  Supporting different databases is pretty much all done behind the scenes.  They have T4 template projects to generate the code for a database from connection information you provide, which shortens the time it takes to get up and running.  It's on [GitHub](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db) and there's an active community working on it.  I even managed to get a pull request into the latest release version :)

One of my current projects connects to several different databases using MySQL, SqlServer, SQLite and - I kid you not - an Access database.  Adding the largest of these (a vendor database with >300 tables and idk how many views) took me about 5 minutes.  The Access database, smallest of the lot, took longer because the vendor in this case built a schema that would make any DBA cry, including adding individual tables to hold job data.  That one was a half hour from start to finish.

Compare that to the 100+ hours I spent building an L2S database library, with all sorts of additional functionality that I thought I needed.  And once I was done it took me days to build a variant for a new database.  Fun, yes, but not productive.

---

For an example, compare this (admittedly bad) `IDbConnection`-based code:

```
    List<(int ID, string FirstName, string LastName)> queryResults = new List<(int ID, string FirstName, string LastName)>();

    using (IDbConnection conn = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (IDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName FROM Users";
            using (IDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (r.NextResult())
                {
                    int id = r.GetInt32(0);
                    string firstname = r.GetString(1);
                    string lastname = r.GetString(2);
                    queryResults.Add((id, firstname, lastname));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

... with this LINQ equivalent:

```
List<(int ID, string FirstName, string LastName)> queryResults = new List<(int ID, string FirstName, string LastName)>();

using (var db = new MyDatabase())
{
    queryResults.AddRange(
        (
            from u in db.Users
            select new { u.ID, u.FirstName, u.LastName }
        )
        .AsEnumerable()
        .Select(r => (r.ID, r.FirstName, r.LastName))
    );
}
```

If I were using a result type instead of Tuples (which LINQ doesn't understand) that would be even simpler.

Comment: Thank you for your idea of Entity Framework and Linq2Sql but from my understanding neither support any NoSQL databases, never mind MongoDB?

Comment: @134395 Sorry, you're right.  NoSQL and LINQ are fundamentally at odds.  You can still use a little LINQ with MongoDB, but every NoSQL has unique methods for accessing it.  Trying to manufacture a consistent interface for them won't work very well.  At best the same style of NoSQL - KV, etc - might work, but it'll be tough.